# Opamp Unity gain follower stability

Tags: operational-amplifier, loop-gain

[image]

Please give explanation considering opamp as ideal one as well as practical one.

Edit:

I got the explanation here.  [Decompensated Operational Amplifiers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Db16d88ZziE&index=3&list=PLiwaj4qabLWwAenk99ONF2_JUjopeAXo4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideal op amp: stable with infinite bandwidth.

Practical:  look for opamps that are guaranteed "unity gain stable" (most modern op amps are unity gain stable).  The bandwidth can be determined by looking at the "unity gain bandwidth" or sometimes the "gain-bandwidth product." The bandwidth can be further limited for large amplitude signals by the slew rate, usually expressed as the change in output voltage per unit time.

Comment: Why was this answer downvote. Restored!

Comment: Sounds good to me too, +1.

Comment: I didn't downvote it but the sloppy capitalisation doesn't help its credibility.

Comment: Just a small correction: Slew rate is usually expressed as the output voltage CHANGE per unit time.

Comment: Thanks for the note on rate of change.  Viva capitalism!

Comment: Might be interesting to note *why* non-unity gain stable amplifiers are useful.

Comment: Regarding stability, something I usually have to watch out for is how much capacitance the op-amp is driving. If it's significant then it will effectively delay the feedback causing the amplifier to be prone to overshoot/"ringing".  See also https://www.analog.com/media/en/analog-dialogue/volume-38/number-2/articles/techniques-to-avoid-instability-capacitive-loading.pdf & https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00884b.pdf